# Change product prices based on category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

What I'm trying to do is change the price of a product, based on which category the customer is shopping in when they add it to the cart. The reasoning for this is that we are selling tours, and the prices change based on what island you are coming from since the tour includes airfare. The categories are set up like this:

```
 |   Oahu | -> |Inter-island|
 |  Maui |  -> |Inter-island|
 | Big Island |  -> |Inter-island|
 | Kauai |-> |Inter-Island|
```

Is there some way to change the price that is being pulled into the cart when the item is added? I have already added custom attributes for each product that contains the price for each island, and it displays correctly in the categories, however the cart is showing only the default price when the tour is added.

I'm not necessarily looking for any code just some ideas on how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add 4 separate tours.  Duplicate your Oahu tour for example and then and simply change the price.

Do you have limited set of seats or something for the tour itself?

Comment: I would agree.  However, if you decide to duplicate the tours, make sure to change the URL Key and if you like, remove the checkbox next to "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL"